# Is it redundant to make final variables private in dart?

Tags: class, flutter, dart, final, private-members

The following class has multiple parameters but only some need to be final; my q is, should I also make these final variables private, or would doing so be redundant?

```
class Car {
    final double _galInFullTank;
    get galInFullTank => _galInFullTank;
    double _miDrivenToEmpty;
    get miDrivenToEmpty => _miDrivenToEmpty;
    double _mpg;
    get mpg => _mpg;

    void update(double newMiDrivenToEmpty) {
        _miDrivenToEmpty = newMiDrivenToEmpty;
        _mpg = _miDrivenToEmpty/_galInFullTank;
    }

    Car({galInFullTank = 12, miDrivenToEmpty = 300}) :
        _galInFullTank = galInFullTank,
        _miDrivenToEmpty = miDrivenToEmpty,
        _mpg = miDrivenToEmpty/galInFullTank;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has some use-cases. It can be used to down-cast variables.

For example, using RxDart we could have:

```dart
final BehaviorSubject<Foo> _foo;
Stream<Foo> get foo => foo;
```

This hides the implementation details.

It could also be used to do extra things inside the getter. For example, Mobx uses that to know what values are used.

But just straight up exposing the variable without modification or extra computation is pointless.

Comment: Ty, your provider package has made Flutter dev much more enjoyable for me! To test my understanding of your answer could you answer this q: Would it be acceptable to make `galInFullTank` public (in my simple situation bc none of your use-cases apply)?

Answer (score 2):

Making a private member `final` is not redundant.  In general, being private and being `final` are orthogonal.  For example, consider something like:

```
class Foo {
  final List<int> someList;
}
```

Just because `Foo.someList` is `final` does not prevent external code from modifying it (e.g. `someFoo.someList.clear()`).

You should make things that you don't want to be part of your API private.